# AngularJS using two controllers in the same view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use make a angularJS web app. I bought a template, which has all of its controllers, routes and directives in a single file `app.js`

This is my first angularJS app, or actually my first front-end work. Trying to be a Full Stack geek now.. :D

So here is now where I am stuck. The app works completely fine, but when I add a new controller `AuthCtrl` which in another file `auth.js` it gives me an error saying `AppCtrl` not found. Following HTML will make you understand it better. I have pointed out where and what is the exact problem in the code snippet.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>PropheSee Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Needs images, font... therefore can not be part of main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css">
    <!-- end Needs images -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

</head>
<body data-ng-app="app" id="app" class="app" data-custom-page="" data-off-canvas-nav="" data-ng-controller="AppCtrl" data-ng-class=" {'layout-boxed': admin.layout === 'boxed' } ">

    <div data-ng-controller="AuthCtrl" data-ng-app="app">
       <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
          {{phone.name}}
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <%-body%>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/ui.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>


    <!-- 
     This is where the problem is. As soon as I add the following line to use AuthCtrl,
     It says AppCtrl not found. Is it that I can't use more than one import for controllers? Or is there a problem in the way I am doing the imports?
    -->
    <script src="scripts/controllers/auth.js"></script>

</body>
```

**Edit - AuthCtrl**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AuthCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

**App.js snippet**

```
(function() {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.chart.ctrls",[])
    .controller("chartCtrl",[
        "$scope",
        function($scope){ ....
```

Comment: Can you put all your files into plnkr? (that can help troubleshoot your issue)

Comment: Okay I will try, never used it before. Also the app.js file from template is about 2500 lines big. :( YOu think I can still pull it out?

Comment: Also when I remove the part that uses AppCtrl, the AuthCtrl part works fine too. Its just that both of them are not working together. If that gives any idea..

Comment: Show us how the auth controller is defined.  I'm pretty sure you are also redeclaring the angular app in there, overriding everything in the app.js file.

Comment: Hell yeah! I think you might be right. Will update the code. Do put it as an answer if it is the problem.

Comment: Just posted an answer :-). Pretty sure thats the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing this in the `auth.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('app',.......
```

Thereby declaring a new app or overwriting the one declared in the `app.js`

Instead you should be using the same app variable that is defined in the `app.js` file.

You need to declare the app and store a reference to it in a variable:

```
var yourApp = angular.module("app.controllers",[.........]);
```

Then to add controllers, assign them to the variable which "holds" the app definition.  This is how the chartCtrl controller should be defined on the `yourApp` application:

```
yourApp.controller("chartCtrl",[
        "$scope",
        function($scope){ ....
```

Then your controller in your auth.js file:

```
yourApp.controller('AuthCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

Comment: They use `angular.module("app.controllers",[]).controller()` to define AppCtrl, but when I do the same for AuthCtrl it gives me the same error. So I can see that the module is again getting replaced. So how do I create a new module? If you want more code I can add it

Comment: Paste the first lines of the app.js in your question.

Comment: Just updated my answer.  Hope you understand.  I believe you might have to remove the (function() { ......... }); surrounding the definition in the app.js file for this to work.

Comment: thank you for your time, you diagnosed the problem promptly. Will make the changes you suggested. That's the right way to do it. But for now I found out that the app.js file also had a definition for the module, with the dependencies. I just added a dependency to the auth controller for now.
I guess the developers of the template haven't written it in a very clean way.. :D